# How can I delay deletion?

Tags: mysql, cron, nestjs

I would like to delay deletion of data from the database. I am using MySQL, nest.js. I heard that CRON is what I need. I want to delete the entry in a week. Can you help me with this? CRON is what I need, or i need to use something another?

Comment: in a week? what does that mean - a week from some event happening? If you mean a week after initiating a DELETE statement then that is not possible. Consider soft deleting with a periodic sweep to physically delete.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, i mean delete after insertion. for example: now i insert user in db, and want to delete it next thursday in same time.

Comment: In that case include a created date in the user table (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) and run an event every day at day end to delete for those created a week ago.

Comment: @P.Salmon thank you for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `cron` job (or `at` in Windows) or a MySQL `EVENT` can be created to periodically check for something and take action.  The resolution is only 1 minute.

If you need a very precise resolution, another technique would be required.  For example, if you don't want to show a user something that is more than 1 week old *to the second*, then simply exclude that from the `SELECT`.  That is add something like this to the `WHERE`:  `AND created_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY`.

Doing the above gives you the freedom to schedule the actual `DELETE` for only, say, once a day -- rather than pounding on the database only to usually find nothing to do.

If you do choose to "pound on the database", be aware of the following problem.  If one instance of the deleter script is running for a long time (for any of a number of reasons), it might not be finished before the next copy comes along.  In some situations these scripts can stumple over each other to the extent of effectively "crashing" the server.

That leads to another solution -- a single script that runs forever.  It has a simple loop:

- Do the actions needed (deleting old rows)
- Sleep 1  -- or 10 or 60 or whatever -- this is to be a "nice guy" and not "pound on the system".

The only tricky part is making sure that starts up after any server restart or crash of the script.

Comment: So, summary its better to have cron job every day and delete by created_at criteria, right?

Comment: @AntonKryukov - In general, SQL is more efficient when works with lots of rows at the same time.  By that, I mean more efficient than handling one row at a time.  If the purge time must (for business reasons) be exactly at some time, then I offer one solution.  If "midnight after 7 days" is "good enough", then I lean toward a batch solution for efficiency reasons.  I've given you an outline of how to do each; do you need more details on one of them?

Comment: Thanks for explanations. No, no details needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a cronjob to periodically delete it.

There are several ways to configure a cron job.

You can write a shell script that periodically deletes entities in the db using linux crontab, or you can configure an application that provides cronjobs such as jenkins or airflow.
AWS lambda also provides cronjob.

Using crontab provided by nestjs seems to be the simplest to solve the problem.

See this link
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling

Comment: Thanks. one more question. is it very expensive for an application to keep all cron tasks?
I mean if I have 1000 users who logged in with 1 second delay from each other.
it is better to leave the script running at 12:00 and doing its job. correctly?

Comment: I think it is not that expensive

Comment: Is that 1000 jobs running?  And are they interacting with each other (the 1-sec delay)?

Comment: the least period between two cronjob is just 1minute.